# Gillette Fusion Proglide in hand luggage

Tags: hand-luggage, trimmer

[Gillette Fusion Proglide](https://www.amazon.in/gp/product/B005SPMINE/ref=sw_img_1?smid=A15APWRK6P7LBV&psc=1) is a combination of disposable razor and trimmer with removable battery. It's very handy while travelling, however I'm not sure whether I should carry it in hand luggage or checked in luggage.

I know that disposable Gillette razors are allowed with hand luggage however given that it is also a trimmer with removable batteries, so I am skeptical if it will be allowed.

Comment: My Gillette razor (not trimmer) has an AA battery in it. My toothbrush has a rechargeable battery in it. Nobody has complained in years about them being in a carry on.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I have the exact same device, have travelled with it multiple times in carry-on baggage, and never had anyone pay it any attention.

Battery-operated devices of any kind are never a problem with carry-on luggage (with the exception of those with extremely large rechargeable batteries, which obviously isn't the case here).

Razors/shavers/etc can be a concern due to sharp edges/blades/etc, however this particular device does not have a exposed blade, and is definitely not 'sharp' in any sense of the word. If you do travel with the razor-style head for it, this would be considered a "[disposable razor](https://www.tsa.gov/travel/security-screening/whatcanibring/items/disposable-razor)" which is allowed in carry-on bags the world over.

So yes, you can travel with this in either your carry-on or checked-in luggage.

Personally I generally place a small piece of paper covering the terminal of the battery before travelling, and then remove it when I arrive.  This removes any possibility of the device turning on during travel.

Comment: if the device did turn on during travel, many people around you would think it was a sex toy, so that is at least one good reason to make sure it doesn't

Comment: @user253751 One of the many reasons I do it :)  The switch does require some pressure to turn on so it's unlikely to happen, but if it did the noise could be "misleading" as you say, not to mention that it could rip it's way through my toiletries case, and/or flatten the battery - none of which would be ideal!

Comment: @user253751 - I don't know; it might be a great way of meeting new and interesting people...

Comment: Doesn't covering the terminals then hit the 'battery outside of its device' rule, as it's not connected to its control technology.

Comment: @Tetsujin, I believe that the battery is installed in the device, but has one end insulated to prevent the flow of electrons. I suppose that one _could_ argue that this is therefore now _not_ installed as the manufacturer intended and therefore doesn't meet the rules, but that screening officer would have to be having one _heck_ of a bad day to be picky about something like that, I'd think. One could argue that the manufacturer initially shipped it that way to prevent batter run-down/accidental power-on when it left the factory & therefore is legal.

Comment: @Tetsujin Even if it does, the battery is a single non-rechargeable AA battery, so no rules apply to it

Comment: The overwhelming majority of humans in the world would assume it's a .......... razor or similar device, or just a phone buzzing.  For, say, 30? years now "devices that buzz!" are just devices.  The "IT'S A SEX TOY!!!!!!!!" trope would have worked in maybe 1970? Late sixties?

Answer (score 6):

Restrictions on batteries are generally imposed to keep the batteries out of the luggage hold.   Depending on the type and capacity of the battery, and in whether the battery is installed in its device or carried as a spare, they are either allowed in both checked and carry-on luggage, prohibited entirely, or allowed in carry-on luggage only.

You haven't given details about the battery in your device, but as far as battery restrictions are concerned, it is almost certainly small enough to be acceptable.  With respect to restrictions on sharp objects, electric shavers and trimmers are permitted.  You should have no trouble with this device.

However, rules may vary from one country to another and from one airline to another, so be sure to check the rules that apply to your flight.

Comment: Thanks. Gillette trimmer i mentioned requires a AA battery.

Comment: @TravellingJuggernaut those come in Li-Ion variants too :)

Answer (score 1):

Restrictions on batteries are specific to Lithium batteries. They must be carry on.

FAA maintains a [list of events](https://explore.dot.gov/t/FAA/views/LithiumBatteries/IncidentDetails?%3Aembed=y&%3AisGuestRedirectFromVizportal=y) related to Lithium Batteries. Some of them involve passengers incorrectly checking in their devices with Lithium batteries, resulting in fires. A general summary of these events can be accessed [here](https://www.faa.gov/hazmat/resources/lithium_batteries/incidents).

One of the more serious event was the [crash of UPS cargo plane](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UPS_Airlines_Flight_6) caused by a large shipment of Lithium Batteries self-igniting. Due to the nature of the fire, standard fire-fighting techniques such as decompressing the cargo bay did not contain the fire because the batteries provide its own oxygen. The fire can actually burn in a vacuum.

Electrical Engineering SE also has a great post on detailing the [dangers of Lithium batteries](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/230164/89413).

Comment: Some lithium batteries are permitted, but discouraged in checked baggage. The [rules are complicated](https://www.faa.gov/sites/faa.gov/files/hazmat/packsafe/resources/Airline_passengers_and_batteries.pdf).